# how to run a PhoneGap program on android emulator?

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, emulation

when i try to run a PhoneGap program in eclipse i find a error:

**[2013-02-13 12:51:21 - DeviceMonitor] 
  Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [2013-  02-13 12:51:22 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1**

OR

**could not find a compatible AVD**

whereas i have android 4.2 and respective emulator of API 17..

Comment: Android user,thank you for your reply!!!

Comment: Android user,i learnt something new... thank you:-)!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [2013-02-13 12:51:21 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [2013- 02-13
>   12:51:22 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

You need to restart your ADB Connection. Open Command prompt(for windows)

**/sdk/platform-tools>  adb -kill server**

Then Start adb server again

**/sdk/platform-tools>  adb -start server**

Now talking about **could not find a compatible AVD**

Check your app compatible android version and create a virtual device accordingly or

1.Right click on project in project explorer in eclipse . 
2.Go to Run -> Run Configurations -> Target Tab

Then choose Radio button

**Always prompt to pick device .**

Apply settings and you will be asked next time to choose the device.

Comment: thanks this was usefull!!
but where do u get the option of kill or start the server???

Comment: now,the problem i am facing is the alert box is not functioning or in that get acceleration....the result does not pop up...
where would i have committed mistake...**i have tried both ways trying out with the example and then by copying all the jar files,js,xmkl and cordova folder **

Comment: well,i could clear the error and run the program successfully...thank you!!

Comment: Thats great. If you find the answer useful then upvote and select it correct as an appreciation and for user assistance.

Comment: JanshairKhan, i can't VoteUp as u need to have 15 reputaions to do that whereas,i have just 1.. now,i cannot answer for any question posted or can't even ask a question from my account.

Answer (score 0):

Go to DDMS and there is a reset adb option, please see the image below:

[image: reset Adb]